# Store AES key in Android

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore

i want to store AES key in AndroidKeyStore on pre-M device

i tried to use key generated with `KeyGenerator`

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
keyGen.init(256);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
```

but i cannot access to that key from KeyStore, later i tried to use `KeyPairGenerator`

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
kpg.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(this)
                .setAlias("alias")
                .build());
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
```

but

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyPairGenerator AES implementation not found

Comment: Check this link
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html

Comment: Hi.. I found some tutorial about how works with AES compatible with pre-M:
https://proandroiddev.com/secure-data-in-android-encryption-in-android-part-1-e5fd150e316f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android Keystore supports AES only since API Level 23 (see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SupportedAlgorithms). On older platforms, you could wrap the AES key using an Android Keystore RSA key. However, this means the AES key's key material will be available inside your app's process, which removes many of the security benefits of using Android Keystore.